# Reader interface and the Read method in golang

Tags: io, go, byte

I was following the golang tour and I have been asked to:

> Implement a rot13Reader that implements io.Reader and reads from an io.Reader, modifying the stream by applying the ROT13 substitution cipher to all alphabetical characters.

I first implemented the method to the *rot13Reader

```
   type rot13Reader struct {
    r io.Reader
}

func (r *rot13Reader) Read(p []byte) (n int, e error){


}
```

However I can't get my head around this Read method.

Does the `p` contain all of the bytes read? And hence all I should do is iterate over them and apply the ROT13 substitution ?

I understand that it should return the number of bytes read and an EOF error at the end of the file however I'm not sure when and how this method is called. So coming back to my original question does the `p` contain all of the data read ? If not then how can I get to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should scan and "rot13" only `n` bytes (the one read by the `io.Reader` within `rot13Reader`).

```
func (r *rot13Reader) Read(p []byte) (n int, e error){
    n, e = r.r.Read(p)
    for i:=range(p[:n]) {
       p[i]=rot13(p[i])
    }
    return
}
```

The `rot13Reader` encapsulate any reader and call `Read` on said encapsulated Reader.
It returns the rot13'ed content, and the number of byte read.

Comment: @Bula I have edited the answer: it was the name the `rot13Reader` receiver. I have changed it to `r`, but it is less clear, as `r` is *also* the name of the `io.Reader` within the `rot13Reader` struct.

Comment: nice answer tnx. Minor detail. In order to work properly I think that you should change the first assignment: n, e = r.r.Read(p) .. for the named return to work properly. Regards

Comment: @FabianoTarlao don't hesitate to edit the answer directly: that would will benefit everybody.

Comment: I updated my comment, @VonC I'm from years in SO but I always thought being a bit "unpolite" doing so. :-) I'm a bit shy. Sorry. I'll do this now. (Furthermore I'm just learning GO so.. I'm a bit still hesitant). I'll do it now.

Comment: @Fab No problem, I will review your edit. Thank you for your contribution