# Implementing Reader interface

Tags: go

I understand the general concept of Go's interfaces. However, I was recently looking into implementing the `io.Reader` interface, and it has me confused. I found this post which didn't help to much.

[Reader interface and the Read method in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25526790/reader-interface-and-the-read-method-in-golang)

To start with, the accepted answer is using `io.Reader`'s `Read` function, which as far as I can tell is never implemented. Second, how does the `Read` function work in the context of something like `ioutil.ReadAll`. It takes something that implemented the `io.Reader` interface and returns a slice of bytes. I don't understand how something that is returning only an `int` and `err` can be processed into a slice of bytes.

Edit:

I was helped in the go-nuts IRC channel and this was the provided answer as to how you would likely actually implement one http://play.golang.org/p/ejpUVOx8jR. Much thanks to the go community.

Edit 2:

as pointed out below the implementation above will fail in the case where the strign is larger than the buffer. This is a more sane implementation http://play.golang.org/p/t4Zg8TnF33.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You pass `Read` the byte slice. `Read` is supposed to put bytes in it. As slices are just references to arrays, changing the contents of a slice changes the underlying array, so the caller of `Read` can then just check the slice it has passed to it.

`ioutil.ReadAll` creates a buffer and calls `ReadFrom` on it. `ReadFrom` calls `Read` repeatedly, increasing the size of the buffer until `Read` tells it has been exhausted by returning `io.EOF` as error. [See for yourself](https://golang.org/src/bytes/buffer.go#L150).

The answer you link does implement the `io.Reader` interface. It is declaring a method `Read(p []byte) (n int, e error)`. That's all what is needed.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't implement the io.Reader interface? http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader. Isn't declaring that method satisfying the io.Reader interface?

Comment: I said "does" implement, not "doesn't". But I'm not sure I understood your question though... You said "as far as I can tell is never implemented".

Comment: Sorry my bad. I think i have been looking over this stuff too long my eyes are bugging out.

Answer (score 8):

The updated answer provided by tez totally works, but here is an alternative that I think is a bit cleaner utilizing Go's `copy`:

```
type Reader struct {
    data []byte
    readIndex int64
}

func (r *Reader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    if r.readIndex >= int64(len(r.data)) {
        err = io.EOF
        return
    }

    n = copy(p, r.data[r.readIndex:])
    r.readIndex += int64(n)
    return
}
```

By using `copy`, you don't have to worry about overflowing `p []byte`.  This also doesn't drain/destroy any state that you have on your reader, instead it just iterates over it with `readIndex`.

Full example here: https://play.golang.org/p/8QTECCkies

This strategy can be seen in some of Go's core packages (ie. https://golang.org/src/strings/reader.go)

Answer (score 1):

Just to note, your implementation of `Read()` method here (http://play.golang.org/p/ejpUVOx8jR) is incorrect. You do not account for a capacity of the provided `p []byte` argument. You'll get an "index out of range" panic if it is smaller than your test string (ex: http://play.golang.org/p/DhcY0hJ0c0).

You might consider a different approach such as this - http://play.golang.org/p/t4Zg8TnF33.

**UPDATE**
I noticed a memory leak in my implementation. The fixed version is here - http://play.golang.org/p/9BbS54d8pb. This goes to show that even a trivial code sometimes is not so trivial :)