# Is there some way to stop/resume file downloading amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I'm downloading csv file from amazon S3 to buffer using aws-go-sdk. I want to parse and proceed it's content simultaniously with downloading. But downloading goes much faster then i can proceed file content, it results in alocating too much  memory. Is there some way to pause/resume downloading process?

```
buff := &aws.WriteAtBuffer{}
s3dl := s3manager.NewDownloader(awsSession)
n, err := s3dl.Download(buff, &s3.GetObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
    Key:    aws.String(key),
})
r := io.Reader(buff.Bytes())
```

Comment: Can you show some key parts of your code? Normally download speed should be adjusted based on how fast you read the response body buffer.

Comment: The speed of a download depends entirely on how fast you consume it. It doesn’t make sense to say that the problem is that the download is faster than you can procede, since that is the optimal situation.

Comment: I'm not asking to change speed. It's obvious that i ask to be able to controll downloading by pause/resume it

Comment: You have to implement your own reader and stop reading at whatever time you want to. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174970/implementing-reader-interface

Comment: Yeah but problem is Download writes to aws.WriteAtBuffer alocating memory for whole file  until downloading is done with uncontrolled speed.